# How do I update a command in git?

Tags: python, git, powershell, heroku

I am totally new to git and heroku. I am trying to deploy an app to heroku but there was a problem and I later realized that I ommitted ':' from my if statement in my python script. I have made the necessary correction, but the deployment is still not successful. I have already run this command `git add app.py`   in my powershell, but I think I am supposed to make an update of this command. Is there a way to make the update or do I run the `git add app.py`  command again?

I am using Microsoft Windows Powershell on Windows 10, and using git version 2.28.0. Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you commit your changes after adding?

Comment: No, I haven't committed it. So do I add the file again before committing or I can straight away commit?

Comment: yeah. you should please check my answer in your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you forgot to commit after adding to staging area

run the following command:

```
$ git add <filename>
$ git commit -m "your message if any"
$ git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't commit your change your changes have not saved to your local repository. So just commit your changes. just follow:

```
git add app.py
git commit -m "your message"
git push heroku master
```

follow the link to know more about `git commit`:
[https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/commands/git-commit#:~:text=The%20%22commit%22%20command%20is%20used,changes%20to%20the%20local%20repository.&text=Using%20the%20%22git%20commit%22%20command,%22git%20push%22%20commands](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/commands/git-commit#:%7E:text=The%20%22commit%22%20command%20is%20used,changes%20to%20the%20local%20repository.&text=Using%20the%20%22git%20commit%22%20command,%22git%20push%22%20commands)).